# Conditional probability - set of conditional probailities

Tags: probability

There is a game where you have

probability of $15 / 320000$ of winning $50

probability of $1/320000$ of winning $100

Let $X$ denote the amount of a win. I am trying to find $P(X=50)$

Would it be

$$P(X=50) = (15/320000) / (1/20000) = 15/16$$

where I have gotten $1/20000$ as the probability of winning any of the two prizes. I check the answer and it is correct but I don't know what "rule" of probability I am using here. I thought it was the law of total probability but looking at wikipedia that is not the case. Can someone break down the rule/law to use to find say $P(X=50)$?

Comment: Your statement has typos.  Correct them.  You have $X_i$ and $X$ - relation?  Your probability for winning  $100$ dollars is not stated consistently.

Comment: @herbsteinberg sorry thats fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using conditional probability. $P(X=50)=P(W=50|Y)$, where $W$ is the outcome of a bet and $Y$ is winning.  I am not sure such a rule has a name.